# ContainerRequestFilter + @Autowired + Null for DAO

Tags: spring, annotations, jax-rs, resteasy

I am implementing the Basic auth for RestEasy API. I tried to implement javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter with annotation @Provider. Everything looks clean until i tried @Autowired my DAO class in my implementation class. Initially, i hard coded my Username & Password in the implemented class and it works. Finally, i started integrating with my DAO class to get those values from DB. But @Autowired annotation is returning null for my DAO. I tried googling and tried lot of option, but still i am getting null for that DAO.

I have annotated my DAO class with @Repository.

```
@Provider
public class SecurityInterceptor implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityDao securityDao;
```

...

```
@Repository("securityDao")
public class SecurityDaoImpl implements SecurityDao {
```

Can someone help me in this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Edit -

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application{


    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons()
    {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
        singletons.add(new SecurityInterceptor());
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

I think i see same issue in this post also.[Spring autowired dao is null](http://Spring%20autowired%20dao%20is%20null). Did anyone have solution for this issue? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: 1. Your filter needs to be managed by String, i.e. make it a `@Component` (or add it as a bean in spring xml). 2. If that still doesn't work, make sure you have properly integrated Spring and RESTeasy.

Comment: Have you included the SecurityDao package in the components scan?

Comment: @peeskillet - I tried that too (@Component). Same SecurityDao is injected properly in my Resources class. I am seeing null only in filter class.

Comment: @Jango - Yes, my Dao package is coming under components scan, as i am getting proper injection in all my Resources class for same Dao.

Comment: Did you instantiate the filter yourself (when registering it), or register it as a class? If the former, maybe that's the problem, I'm not sure. I've never used Spring with RESTeasy, so I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: @peeskillet - Thanks for your time and info. I am registering my filter class like above edit.

Comment: Try and register it as a class in the override of `Set<Class<?>> getClasses()` instead of instantiating it in `getSingletons()`. Either way, it will still be a singleton, because it is a filter

Comment: @peeskillet - Even registering in getClasses() is having same issue. :(